# How to create loop partition from already existing partition

Tags: linux, command-line, partitioning

I believe /images/backups is using the space in /images ?

```
/dev/sdb1             820G  645G  135G  83% /images
/dev/loop0            296G  296G     0 100% /images/backups
```

I've a similar kind of partition in another machine /images which is 500G free, and I would want to take out 350G for /images/backups, how to do it ?

Is it right that, it is a simple loop mount which can give specified amount of space or we should create a NULL file of required size and mount ? If so, what are the mount options should be used to specify the size ?

Comment: This isn't actually enough information to know where the file backing /dev/loop0 is -- it may or may not be /images. The "losetup" command will tell you this.

Comment: losetup /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0: [0811]:45585 (/images/backups.img), so it is a NULL file which is created in that partition ?

Comment: Nothing 'NULL' about it, but yes, it lives in /images then.

Comment: ...by the way, in the future, ServerFault would probably be a better place for this kind of question (which is more a sysadmin thing than a programming thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create the destination with a fixed size, but can use a "sparse file" which doesn't actually have any blocks written to it yet (and which thus doesn't actually consume space until you write to it).

For instance:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.img bs=1 count=0 seek=20G
```

will create a sparse file preallocated to 20GB. That said, actually writing 20GB of zeros to disk up-front (making the file non-sparse) will be faster on writes and lead to less fragmentation.

This can be attached to a loopback device with the losetup command, have a filesystem created, and be mounted:

```
losetup /dev/loop1 file.img
mke2fs -j /dev/loop1
mount /dev/loop1 /mnt/somewhere
```

If you want to know if an existing file is sparse, the following will do the trick (on a system with GNU tools; some of the below is not supported in a pure POSIX environment):

```
{
    read block_count block_size file_size
    if (( block_count * block_size < file_size )) ; then
        echo "Sparse"
    else
        echo "Non-Sparse"
    fi
} < <(stat --format='%b %B %s'$'\n' /images/backups.img)
```